# Interpretation of a partly continuous variable

Tags: regression, logistic, interpretation, continuous-data

I have a variable that reflects the prices of a product. It has the typical amounts such as 9.99, 14.99 sometime more random like 18.95 etc. I believe, I can still consider it a continuous variable?! What would be my interpretation if my outcome variable is sale success (binary, using a logistic regression). What exactly is the incremental increase here? I want to be accurate, but I’m not confident I can use: an increase by 1 cent would result in an increase in sale success by a multiplicative factor of e.g. 2.5. Please help me with the interpretation here

Comment: If the outcome is sale yes/no modeled as a function of price in the form you describe above, the interpretation of the slope coefficient is a log-odds ratio for a sale comparing products differing by $1 in price. There's no issue in having an imbalanced predictor. It is good, regardless of the distribution of the predictor, to assess the model for possible non-linearity e.g. by fitting higher order polynomial terms.

Comment: Prices are discrete in principle but approximately continuous in practice unless the step between possible prices is large enough to bite. Sale success is on the face of it entirely binary: there was or was not a sale. Otherwise I am not clear what you're asking. Why is 18.95 more random than 9.99? There is no mystery about predicting a binary variable from a continuous variable. We do it all the time. Rain or snow from temperature; survived 1 year from age or birth weight, etc.

Comment: Technically it's feasible but you'd need to examine the trend very carefully. Pricing is not a simple process, while quantitatively it's sensible in regression domain to think that a 25c increase is a 25c increase, jumping from, say 9.00 to 9.25 could be quite difference from 9.99 to 10.24, because the customer's psychology is also playing a role here.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I might have been not very clear. All I am asking is: Is the incremental increase 1cent, 1$ or anything else I should consider.

Comment: ^ Interpreting "per what unit of increase" basing on dollar, cent, or million dollar is up to you. You'll just need to rescale it. Usually, the hypothetical unit increase should be realistic. If the industry tend to adjust price in segments of 10c, then it's more useful for the industry audience if you use 10c as the unit.

Comment: That is the problem I have, there is no "standard unit increase" if charges are 64.95, 66.95 59.95, 104,95 it seems like I can use 1$ as the one unit increment. I don't think I need to rescale. Would you agree or would you suggest to rescale?